# URL routing with types

Tags: craft3, url, routing

We need to setup following URL:

```
DOMAIN/{lang}/{family}/offers/{slug}
```

e.g.:

```
example.com/en/Larsen/offers/example
```

What do we need to configure our section URL? Have anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of field of family ?
You don't have to enter the domain and language. Just start from family and forward. If family is the title field, write it like this:

```
{title}/offers/{slug}
```

if the family field is an element type, do it like this:

```
{familyField.last().uri}/offers/{slug}
```

or

```
{familyField.last().slug}/offers/{slug}
```

or if it is a title

```
{title}/offers/{slug}
```

Comment: What we can do: We have more then one family for a offer (slug). I mean we should take a offer to x families.